# Locking entities to perform get-update-set operations in Google Cloud datastore

Tags: python, multithreading, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

What is the recommeneded way to lock an entity (e.g. User(amount_earned)) to perform consistent read --> update --> set operations on Google Cloud Datastore.

Using memcache, we usually do a memcache.add(lock_key), to make sure there is only process/thread modifying a object.

Since memcache's add is atomic and returns false, if key wasn't previously added, it is easy to simulate "locking" using memcache.

How can one simulate similar locking semantic on Google Cloud datastore.

Ideally

```
with gcp.lock(lock_key)as key:
   user.get(user_id) # read
   user.update(amount) # update
   user.set() # save

# Release the lock, so that other processes can now updated user (identified by user_id) object
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could perhaps use [Transactions](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions) and [Optimistic Locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) strategy.

Let's take the example of updating User entity. In order to use optimistic locking, you would have to use a special property (e.g. entity version). The version field will be incremented by one for each update. Steps to update an entity:

1. Load the entity
2. Assume you have a UI that allows updating of User entity. Display the entity on the screen in Edit mode.
3. End user reviews/makes changes to the entity
4. End user clicks Save
5. Now start a transaction
6. Load the User entity using the entity's Key
7. Compare the version of newly loaded entity and the entity previously loaded to the UI
8. If the versions match, no one else updated the entity, so go ahead and update the entity and commit the transaction. Make sure to increment the version number while updating/committing. If the versions do not match, someone else changed the entity. Do not update the entity, rollback the transaction. Take appropriate action. For example, you can display a message to the user and have him review the latest entity and make any further changes.

Comment: This is great! But there could still be race-conditions between [7] and [8] right.

There can be more than one thread doing steps [7] and [8] at the same time?

Comment: Yes, that will be taken care by the transaction. The first transaction that commits wins and the second transaction fails. That is document in the link I posted. It says - **Inside of transactions, serializable isolation is enforced. This means that another transaction cannot concurrently modify the data that is read or modified by this transaction. **

Comment: It looks like no two transactions can update an entity at the same time. Cloud datastore makes sure that transacations are serialized. So, an application needs to implement optimistic locking only if there are update operations that are happening without using transactions, right?

Comment: If you want to use **just** Transactions, you have to do Step #1 in the above example in a transaction, of course all subsequent steps would be different. Depending on your application (do you update entities programmatically or humans update the entities), you may still need the application level optimistic locking. Without it, you may end up updating a stale entity overwriting changes made by another transaction.